# Regarding In App Purchase in Game Maker Through Google Play

Tags: in-app-purchase, game-maker

I am developing a game where I would like to use Google IAP service.

While testing with test ID, I got one issue.

I placed show_message_async on IAP Event but even after payment is successful the message does not appear.

Below is the code:

**Execute Code in IAP Event :**

```
var i, q;
q = iap_event_queue();
repeat (ds_queue_size(q))
{
    i = ds_queue_dequeue(q);
    if ( i == 0 )
    {
        if ( iap_is_purchased("android.test.purchased") )
        {
            iap_consume("android.test.purchased");
            show_message_async("Purchased...");
        }
    }
}
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose you are using Game Maker Studio?

Comment: Yes. I am using Game Maker Studio.

Comment: I don't have experience with IAP. I'm sorry, but I can't help you.

Comment: Please check that ds_queue isn't empty with `ds_queue_empty(q)`. Also check iap_store_status description in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

did you try?

```
show_message("Purchased...");
```